# Sorting Floors within a Building

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database of equipment that needs to serviced across a number of floors within various buildings.

Currently the floor numbers are held within a CHAR(2) field whereby I input to the following rules:

- -1 for Basement
- 0 for Ground Floor
- 1 for first floor
- 2 for second floor
- etc
- For any loft or roofspace, I add 1 to the highest floor number within that building.

The equipment is then listed so that the equipment at the lowest floor number is serviced first and the servicing technician will work their way from bottom to top.

The above has worked to date, however with the introduction of some new buildings I'm not sure how to treat the following floors so that the equipment is still listed from bottom to top floor:

- Lower Ground Floor / Ground Floor / Upper Floor
- Intermediate Floor - A floor space that is between two other floors e.g. between first floor and second floor.

Should I use a different data type or how could I input these floors to ensure they sort from the lowest floor?

Comment: I'd definitely be using a signed integer for those, and then just assign them in numerical order of floor, surely is the most logical answer? Alternatively, you could sub-divide floors with a float to account for mezzanines, but that seems excessive, since the building will already have a predetermined number of floors (if a new floor gets added to a building, it'll likely always be above the current top floor, with a few exceptions of course)..

Comment: I can think of two options: 1) have additional rules, so that intermediate floors are halfway values (2.5, 3.5) or 2) instead of CHAR(2) use decimal numbers to represent floors. For 'upper floor', 'lower ground' etc. is the issue that these are different names than your rules are set for?

Comment: I have thought about having decimal values so -0.5 for lower ground, 0 for ground and 0.5 for upper ground, but my concern is usability - would the technician understand what floor -0.5 means? I was therefore just wondering if there's any alternative solution that I hadn't thought of - appreciate the feedback, thanks

Comment: In addition, there are scenarios where there's an upper ground floor and then a mezzanine above that but below the first floor - so in decimal this would be 0.5 for upper ground, 0.75 for mezzanine and 1 for first floor - this then starts to get a bit messy I feel?

Comment: There is a convention that uses 0 for the lowest floor - regardless of how humans actually refer to it.

Comment: Safest will be to have an additional column, so you can have FloorID which can be LG, G, M, 1 etc, and FloorPosition which can be simple integers 0-n